# PHP array to stars

Tags: php

I have array with values:
`7.09,  5.63  , 5.35  , ...`

I'm rounding them to **0.5** with:

```
round(x * 2) / 2;
```

Now I have `7, 6, 5.5`

How can I make stars by these? Max stars 5. So I need to make 5 stars = highest array value, what's then? Sorry for my bad english. I don't know what should I do.

7 - 5 stars

6 - 4.5 stars

5.5 - 4 stars

Comment: What do you mean by stars? Is it an image source? Do you have any html code?

Comment: convert it to percents

Comment: It looks like he wants to give an average grade.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos it's like rating stars. I'll use fontawesome. http://fontawesome.io/icon/star/ and http://fontawesome.io/icon/star-o/ for empty

Comment: Do the conversion need to be linear. It's not in your example.

Comment: So what are the RULES. i.e. what numbers cause what stars

Comment: Whatever the rules are, you probably shouldn't be rounding twice. Just use your original values to get the most accurate results on a 10-point scale.

Comment: @jeroen then how can I make 5 stars? Not 10

Comment: 5 stars including half stars is still a 10-point scale...

Comment: [Cross multiplication.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mArray = array(8,2,5,1);


$biggestNumber = max($mArray);


foreach($mArray as $index => $star){
    $percent =  $star / $biggestNumber * 100;
    $mFinalArray[$index]['number'] = $star;
    $mFinalArray[$index]['stars'] = $percent / 100 * 5;
}

print_r($mFinalArray);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 8
            [stars] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
            [stars] => 1.25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 5
            [stars] => 3.125
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [stars] => 0.625
        )

)
```

Also if you want round numbers, you could change the last line from

`$mFinalArray[$index]['stars'] = $percent / 100 * 5;`

to

`$mFinalArray[$index]['stars'] = round($percent / 100 * 5);`

Example output using `round` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 8
            [stars] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2
            [stars] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 5
            [stars] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [stars] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get an average of your first integers, out of 5, just do a conversion (use the max to get max value = 5 stars) :

```
max = 7.09
a = 7.09
b = 5.63

starsA = (a/max)* 5
starsB = (b/max)* 5
```

and then round these values to get your stars on that 10-point scale.